# Why keytool -exportcert doesn't ask for keypasswd?

Tags: java, keytool

The doc states:
"You will always need this password in order to access the keystore entry containing that key."

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/step3.html

But whatever keypasswd I set I can export the certificate without it, and the resulting file are all binary equal.

Why don't we need to specify the keypasswd to export the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exported certificate is a PUBLIC KEY so it doesn't require password (Is not meant to be protected) what you actually protect is a KEYSTORE (Combination of public + private keys) that's why keytool doesn't require password for export public keys...